# How to make another route after login in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controllers

I want to make another route after I logged in.
Now it's going to public/home, but I want it go to another route, like time day.

I posted the code here about the routes.
As you can see it now goes to `HomeController@index`, but I want that to go to `TimedayController@index`.

I hope someone can help me out!

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

//timeday Routes
  Route::group(['middleware'=> 'web'],function(){
  Route::resource('timeday','\App\Http\Controllers\TimedayController');
  Route::post('timeday/{id}/update','\App\Http\Controllers\TimedayController@update');
  Route::get('timeday/{id}/delete','\App\Http\Controllers\TimedayController@destroy');
  Route::get('timeday/{id}/deleteMsg','\App\Http\Controllers\TimedayController@DeleteMsg');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` and find `LoginController` (laravel 5.4) or `AuthController` (older versions) and just write

```
protected $redirectTo = '/mypath/to/page'; (here placed '/home')
```

Comment: I have done the next:
protected $redirectTo = '/timeday/index/'; ('/index')

But it still not working for me maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: just `/timeday` cause you define it as resource

Comment: you can see all routes that your applications have by running console command `php artisan route:list`. And if you define resource like this `Route::resource('timeday', ...)` it already have required pathes for update and delete so you dont need to define it

Comment: It is in a separated folder in the resources folder: timeday and in that folder there is a file called index.blade.php that i want to show

Comment: you must set redirect to route! not to view. its a standard architecture of laravel application. You define route, then you define function of controller that matches this route, This function get data from models or doing some work and then you are rendering view

Comment: Route::get('/index', '\App\Http\Controllers\TimedayController@index')->name('index');

Like this?

Comment: 1. you define route in your (routes/web.php file) like Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about'); 2. Then you writes controller PagesController with function about. 3 in function about you write `return view('path to view)

Comment: Never mind i just fixed it :) Thanks for your help and inspiration!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just after basic CRUD functionality on your timeday controller you can just have `Route::resource('timeday','TimedayController');`.  This will automatically handle the routing to the controllers you want to use https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers. Note the 'Actions handled by controller' section.  This would mean that you can go to [localhost.com/public/timeday](http://'') and you will be taken to the `photos.index` controller.

Assuming you are working in the default web routes file you also can take out `middleware=>web` as that is inserted by default to all the routes in that file https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#middleware-groups.

So your code will end up looking something like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

/* assuming you don't need authentication on home page */
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

//timeday Routes
Route::resource('timeday','TimedayController');
```

When it comes to authorization there are a few things you can do but the best place to get started is by reading the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication